# FaaS least cost routing - comparable billing model?

Tags: cloud-computing

I want to implement "FaaS least cost routing".

It does not make sense to calculate the costs before every request, but calculating the cheapest provider on a daily or hourly basis would make sense.

My question is specific to FaaS. No storage is involved.

As far as I know up to now the FaaS providers (Google, AWS, Azure, ...) all have a different interface. But this could be solved with a wrapper.

I think the difficult part is to automatically compare the costs.

Do cloud providers have a comparable billing model?

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong with this question.

Comment: This question is not very clear, and none of your assumptions are backed by any references. Perhaps this is the reason for the down-votes.

Comment: @LucasRamage you are right. I removed the assumptions.

Comment: @guettli I would suggest you reword question toward "how you could make it", providing more specific requirements, unlike currently "does it exists" because software recommandation are offtopic.

Comment: If there is a least-cost routing for FaaS, it would be the province of the service provider.  In other words, you wouldn't benefit, unless *their* LCR was passed onto you in the form of cost savings.

Comment: @RobertHarvey at the stock market, there is a broker which handles this. The broker is not selling something. He brings the two parties (the selling (provider) and the buying (consumer) party) together. If you compare this to FaaS, then there are several parties who offer a service (amazon, google, azure, ...) and several consumers. The least cost routing does not get done by the service providers. At least that's what I think makes sense.

Comment: You would have to subscribe to multiple providers, and then build something that determines which provider your request gets sent to via an algorithm.  I would think that would sort of defeats the purpose of using a cloud provider in the first place, since their job is to give you that economy of scale already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there are several aspects. If several providers can give you scalability then the next aspect is the money.

Comment: Scalability *is* money.  It costs money to have multiple providers. So any cost savings would have to be offset by the additional time, money and effort you spend maintaining multiple providers and switching between them.  It's almost certainly spending dollars to save nickels.

Comment: What *specific* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DanWilson The problem I want to solve: I want to spent less money on FaaS.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you say "Scalability is money". That's true. But in the FaaS context you only pay for the traffic you create. Up to now the vendor-lock-in is still exists. Making code portable to several cloud providers is still work. But think this extra work will decrease in the next years. And then everybody wants least-cost-routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***No, however there are frameworks available to enable easily migrating between cloud providers.***

The basis for my answer is found within the definitions provided below.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_as_a_service),

> a category of cloud computing services that provides a platform allowing customers to develop, run, and manage application functionalities without the complexity of building and maintaining the infrastructure typically associated with developing and launching an app.

Likewise, [Least-cost routing (LCR)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-cost_routing) is defined as follows:

> the process of selecting the path of outbound communications traffic based on cost.

Public cloud companies provide integrations and functionality that is not easily portable to other providers. In practice, most companies end up being locked in to certain providers due to these architectural differences. Therefore, unless developing separate codebases that perform the same task, (which would be redundant), there is no way to leverage the cost savings found on another provider without accouting for these changes.

While recommendations are off-topic, I can provide two arbitrary examples of frameworks that provide the portability required to enable rapid transitions between various cloud services.

- [Knative](https://knative.dev) is a kubernetes-based solutions for running "serverless" code.
- [Serverless](https://serverless.com) is a framework for deploying functions as a service.